# How to "Quick Export as PNG" in photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, javascript

I use photoshop CS6 for batch editing high number of images because I can clone it by sandboxie software and it is very lite.
but there is a problem, CS6 have not "Quick Export as PNG" feature.
If it possible please provide a script for "Quick Export as PNG" in CS6.

i wrote following script but sometimes it show "Save As..." window and stop my batch editing action process:

```
// Save as PNG script with compression and without "Save As..." window for Photoshop CS6

// Set the target folder path for saving the PNG file
var destinationFolder = new Folder("~/Desktop/"); // Replace with your desired folder path

// Check if the destination folder exists, create it if necessary
if (!destinationFolder.exists) {
  destinationFolder.create();
}

// Set the active document
var doc = app.activeDocument;

// Set the options for saving as PNG
var options = new PNGSaveOptions();
options.interlaced = false;
options.compression = 9; // Adjust compression value (0-9) to control file size and quality
options.sRGBProfile = false; // Prevents the "Save As..." window from appearing

// Get the base name of the active document
var docName = doc.name;
var baseName = docName.substring(0, docName.indexOf('.'));

// Build the destination file path
var destinationFile = new File(destinationFolder + "/" + baseName + ".png");

// Save the active document as PNG
doc.saveAs(destinationFile, options);

// Close the active document without saving changes
doc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
```

I don't know how to remove "Save As..." window from above script

Comment: We get that you seem to be single-minded in this task of yours, but we're not here to be a free script-writing service, especially for out of date software few of us even remember from a decade ago.

Comment: @Tetsujin post edited

Answer (score -1):

I fixed problem of that script by changing `doc.saveAs(destinationFile, options);` to `doc.saveAs(destinationFile, options, true);`